# Headless Chrome downloading low resolution images

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I am making a simple **scraper** as my first python script. Everything works fine in normal chrome, but when I try the headless chrome, all images downloaded are very low res

The images are being downloaded from Google, and I imagine that the problem is Google isn't loading the high resolution image because there is no display.

```
print(finalwords)

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.maximize_window()


def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.google.com/"
    browser.get(url)
    search_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input [@title='Pesquisar']")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    image_button = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Imagens")
    image_button.click()
    href = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rg_s"]/div[1]/a[1]').get_attribute("href")
    print("href: " + str(href))
    browser.get(href)
    time.sleep(1)
    src = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="irc_cc"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img').get_attribute("src")
    print("src: " + str(src))
    try:
        arquivo = os.path.join("D:/A/scriptm/Redbone", i + ".png")
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(src), arquivo)
        print("saved!\n")
    except:
        print("error saving!\n")


searchterms = (finalwords)
for i in searchterms:
    print(i)
    get_results(i)
```

The script is first "opening the image on a new tab" and downloading the high resolution one. But in headless mode, it downloads a low resolution one, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: show relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting window size

```
options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080"); //c#
```

however it probably wont help if you are running your code from some system account and not as user. You can read about it here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/70v46v/chrome_resolution_problem_on_windows_server/

Firefox allows you to set window size larger than the system resolution, but I haven't been able to make it work on server yet.